# Writing a streamed cross-reference in PDF: file is detected as damaged?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am using Typescript to write a streamed cross-reference table at the end of my PDF file, as suggested the answer from my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867578/pdf-incremental-update-for-digital-signatures-works-with-regular-xref-table-br)

Here is the XREF table I would have written without stream:

```
xref
0 1
0000000000 65535 f 
21 2
0000084670 00000 n 
0000085209 00000 n 
73 6
0000085585 00000 n 
0000086335 00000 n 
0000150988 00000 n 
0000151086 00000 n 
0000151528 00000 n 
0000151707 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 79
/Root 21 0 R
/Info 19 0 R
/Prev 116
>>
startxref
152861
%%EOF
```

And here is the streamed version:

```
79 0 obj
<<
/Type /XRef /Filter /FlateDecode
/Root 21 0 R
/Info 19 0 R
/Index [0 1 21 2 73 7 ] /W[1 3 0] /DecodeParms<</Columns 4/Predictor 12>> /Prev 116 /Length 45 /Size 80>>
stream
(...data..)
endstream
endobj
startxref
152870
%%EOF
```

As for the content of the stream, here it is in a byte array form. It was deflated using Poko.deflate() with the default compression level:

120,156,99,98,0,2,38,70,70,175,125,76,140,12,76,210,64,130,177,2,196,122,7,36,254,244,2,9,134,36,144,216,46,16,107,51,144,96,105,2,0,141,44,6,140

I have reversed the process I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791861/trying-to-understand-data-in-cross-reference-xref-stream-in-pdf)

The arranged inflated version is as follow:

```
02 00 00 00 00
02 01 01 4a be // = 84670    -> object 21 is at byte position 84670
02 01 00 02 1b // = 539      -> object 22 is at byte position 85209
02 01 00 01 78 // = 376      -> object 73 is at byte position 85585
02 01 00 02 ee // etc
02 01 00 fc 8d
02 01 00 00 62
02 01 00 01 ba
02 01 00 00 b3
02 01 00 04 82
```

However, when I try and open the resulting file, all I get is:

[image]

What am I missing? The most odd thing about this process is the leading "02" on each line (found in the referenced post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791861/trying-to-understand-data-in-cross-reference-xref-stream-in-pdf)). However, even without it, the same problem seems to occur. What am I missing?

Comment: Please share the whole PDF for analysis.

Comment: Here you go: https://easyupload.io/4z0gfc

Comment: Problem 1, your startxref offset is wrong, you have to point to the start of the indirect object, not the direct object therein. But there are other errors still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 problems can be identified easily.

#### Incorrect startxref offset

Your startxref points to the start of the stream dictionary but it should point to the object number of the indirect object housing the stream.

#### Missing predictor bytes

You claim that the *arranged inflated version* is

```
02 00 00 00 00
02 01 01 4a be // = 84670    -> object 21 is at byte position 84670
02 01 00 02 1b // = 539      -> object 22 is at byte position 85209
02 01 00 01 78 // = 376      -> object 73 is at byte position 85585
02 01 00 02 ee // etc
...
```

But inflating your stream gives

```
00 00 00 00
01 01 4a be
01 00 02 1b
01 00 01 78
01 00 02 ee
...
```

I.e. you forgot to add the predictor bytes.

#### Prediction only applied to offsets

You fixed the two errors mentioned above and shared that file. Looking at that file another error became clear: You only apply the prediction to the offset part of the cross reference entry, not to the initial byte indicating the type of the entry!

Your inflated stream is now as follows

```
 02, 01, 01, 4a, be,
 02, 01, 00, 02, 1b,
 02, 01, 00, 01, 78,
 02, 01, 00, 02, ee,
 02, 01, 00, fc, 8d,
 02, 01, 00, 00, 62,
 02, 01, 00, 01, bc,
 02, 01, 00, 00, b3,
 02, 01, 00, 04, 82
```

Resolving the prediction, therefore, results in

```
 01, 01, 4a, be,
 02, 01, 4c, d9,
 03, 01, 4d, 51,
 04, 01, 4f, 3f,
 05, 01, 4b, cc,
 06, 01, 4b, 2e,
 07, 01, 4c, ea,
 08, 01, 4c, 9d,
 09, 01, 50, 1f
```

This contains a lot of incorrect type bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I have moved the startxref location at the start of the object. As for the predicator byte "2", I forgot I had commented the line that adds it. When I add it back, sadly the problem persists.

Comment: Update: I found my array wasn't long enough, and the last objects were not listed in the table (thanks javascript for the silent error). Now, I get a blank PDF with the same error as in my original post "Expected a dict object". If you want to have a look at the current PDF: https://easyupload.io/p5352r

Comment: Ok, there was another bug I didn't immediately see, compare my edit to my answer.

Comment: Right! I didn't catch that, thanks!. So I did the correction, and now there is no error when opening the file. However, all the updates I did in my incremental update (adding a signature) are non-existant in the resulting PDF. If you want to have a look at the resulting PDF: https://easyupload.io/pvk290

There should be a big red square at the bottom right as a visual signature

Comment: Great news! I have found a solution. I removed the /DecodeParams, the predicator bytes and put the bytes directly instead of the difference to the previous value, and everything works as expected now.

Comment: Great. Well, the prediction stuff actually only is an attempt to optimize the data for compression, it is not required at all, and without it implementation is easier.

Comment: @mkl If I may follow up on this one: Where do you get your "Incorrect startxref offset" information from? Because from the specification it definitely seems that it should be the start of the object (e.g. "`10 0 obj`"), but experimentation with Acrobat Reader suggests that Acrobat produces files where `startxref` points to the `<<...` of the `/XRef` stream dictionary (and they're linearized files, too, just for fun). And now I am confused. I'm looking at Appendix F.3.11 and Section 7.5.8.1 in the PDF 1.7 spec, for reference. Cheers!

Comment: @Gebodal *'from the specification it definitely seems that it should be the start of the object (e.g. "`10 0 obj`")'* - Correct. *'experimentation with Acrobat Reader suggests that Acrobat produces files where `startxref` points to the `<<...` of the `/XRef` stream dictionary'* - That would be incorrect. To check this I just created a linearized PDF with the current Acrobat but both `startxref` and `/Prev` correctly pointed to the object number.